# Unable to write date field in Dataframe to csv using Scala

Tags: apache-spark-sql

While writing a Dataframe to csv ld in Scala the date field is getting converted to number like - 1479740431158000

I tried following various options but none worked

Is there any way to get the field written in csv in correct format?
I am using Spark 2.0

```
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("dateFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("dateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssS").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:S").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
scala> tgt.printSchema
root
 |-- empno: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- message_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deptno: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- md5value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- batchid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- currind: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- update_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with Spark 2.0.0 for writing the date format but this issue has been fixed in Spark 2.0.1. Please check https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/392. Also you should use "csv" instead of "com.databricks.spark.csv" as this has been included in latest version of apache-spark. So you can use like

```
tgt.write.format("csv").option("header", "false").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd").save("/data/mi30/apps.csv")
```